# Getting duplicate image saved on uploading via modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I made an image uploader on modal window..its working fine. The modal opens and uploading image it saves one image and works fine!!
Then on closing modal and opening it again and trying to show image in modal, then the problem starts as it saves the duplicate image upto 2-4 random times. Thought like it is because of saved event so tried preventDefault but didn't work..or is there any way by which i can fully destroy this ajax call then that might work. What are your opinions to fix this problem ?

Ajax

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#form').live('change', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'uploadajax.php',
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#throw').html("working..");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#form').ajaxForm({                  
                    target: '#throw',
                }).submit();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Server side

```
<?php
$path = "upload/";

if ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "") {
    echo 'no file';
} else {

    if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
            || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))) {

        if ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif") {
            $ext = 'gif';
        }
        if ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") {
            $ext = 'jpeg';
        }
        if ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg") {
            $ext = 'jpg';
        }
        if ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") {
            $ext = 'jpeg';
        }
        if ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png") {
            $ext = 'png';
        }
        if ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png") {
            $ext = 'png';
        }

        $img_url1 = rand(111111, 999999) . time() . substr(str_replace(" ", "_", 9999), 1);

        $img_url1 = $img_url1;

        $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path . $img_url . "." . $ext)) {



            $link = $path . $img_url;

            $link1 = "$link.$ext";

            unset($tmp);
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file error';
    }
}
?>
```

Modal Window

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.uploadme').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'uploadbox.php',
            beforeSend: function(data){
                box.dialog({
                    message: "Setting up upload box",
                    animate: false,
                    title: "<center>Upload Box</center>"
                });
            },
            success: function(data){
                box.hideAll()
                box.dialog({
                    animate: false,
                    message: data,
                    title: "<center>Upload Box</center>"
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not think its your ajax call. I think its your modal window for uploading image. Do you clear the data after upload ? Or destroy is completely ?

Comment: Yes, Anand i tried to clear the data. but its not working i think its still saved

Comment: Anand have look that modal window i've edited